Computationally efficient alternative to row-wise apply on a list with same-length vectors
I have a list of same-length vectors that I need to run different statistical functions on per vector element across the list. I know I can do this with apply by creating a data frame first and then running the function row-wise:
apply(X = do.call(what = "data.frame", args = foo), MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sum", na.rm = TRUE)

This process is very slow though when run a couple hundred thousand times.
With Reduce I managed to get a partial solution, e.g. when using + instead of sum, which is a lot faster:
Reduce(f = "+", x = foo)

Though, I did not manage to get the pure Reduce version working with functions like mean, sd, and others, as well as regarding the argument na.rm = TRUE.
A sub-optimal solution to speed things up a little while relying on apply still is just speeding up the matrix creation with Reduce:
apply(X = Reduce(function(...) cbind(...), foo), MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sum", na.rm = TRUE)

Here is reproducible example and a comparison of the solutions I came up with so far.
foo <- lapply(X = 1:1e2, FUN = function(x) 1:10)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark("apply_do.call" = apply(X = do.call(what = "data.frame", args = foo), MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sum", na.rm = TRUE),
                               "apply_Reduce" = apply(X = Reduce(f = function(...) cbind(...), x = foo), MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sum", na.rm = TRUE),
                               "Reduce" = Reduce(f = "+", x = foo))

Which results in the following output on my machine (Linux)
Unit: microseconds
          expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 apply_do.call 4256.337 4406.775 5211.12032 4603.8670 5180.1275 13508.14   100   c
  apply_Reduce  292.775  326.124  480.88223  346.5525  436.1935  7559.97   100  b 
        Reduce   37.505   43.197   51.53856   46.7935   55.2790   131.72   100 a 

As you can see, the potential for computational improvements is drastic with the Reduce version only needing about 1 % of computation time compared to the first example.
Is there a way to get an efficient solution to my problem (compatibility with min, max, sum, mean, sd, ...) without relying on external libraries? Bonus points if the answer manages to correctly compute statistics like mean and sd as well as preserving object types like POSIXct.

You can check additional solutions with collapse: dapply(foo, sum, MARGIN = 1), or, to convert the list to a matrix/df, check unlist2d(foo) or the base R list2DF

The matrixStats package is your friend. apply is designed for matrices and applying it on data.frames is very inefficient. Since you appear to have only numbers, there's no need for a data.frame. Try using cbind instead, to get a matrix. In addition, use the cpp functions like matrixStats::rowSums2.
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   apply_df=apply(do.call("data.frame", foo), 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE),
+   apply_mat=apply(do.call("cbind", foo), 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE),
+   ms=matrixStats::rowSums2(do.call(what="cbind", args=foo)), 
+   "Reduce"=Reduce(f="+", x=foo),
+   check='equal')
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min        lq        mean    median         uq       max neval cld
  apply_df 9210.000 9446.8110 10276.74015 9648.5480 10090.6055 18426.747   100  a 
 apply_mat   93.513   97.9100   106.15389  103.0785   107.2585   147.374   100   b
        ms   39.493   42.3560    49.29303   47.4105    53.4270    99.889   100   b
    Reduce   72.032   75.5015    84.13138   80.2595    86.5755   128.951   100   b

There's also matrixStats::rowMins, matrixStats::rowMaxs, matrixStats::rowSds and many more, could get your friend.

Thanks for the detailed reply. As I am relying on base R, apply on matrix is efficient enough for me. Trying to conserve attributes, e.g. POSIXct, makes it kind of complicated time-wise. One solutions contains transforming the vectors to lists before doing the "cbind", then running the functions on the new colums. Takes a lot more time though -- i will have to consider the benefit.

@oepix I see, perhaps an option could be store and reassign attributes a <- attributes(x); dostuff(as.matrix(x)); x <- as.data.frame(x); attributes(x) <- a or sth similar, depends on the case

Yes, this is a nice solution and the performance drop is negligible! I'm trying to think of cases where it would be inappropriate, but for basic object types I don't see any reason against it, or do you disagree? I will update my question soon with the solutions to an inherently type-conserving (but slow-ish) and your proposed quasi-type-conversing approach. thanks for your support!

@oepix One thing I can think of is to be careful when matching back the attributes, where (row.)names can be helpful. Also, if somehow NAs get omitted during calculations we should take "na.action" attribute into account, e.g. as in na.omit(c(1, 2, 3, NA)).

If all lists are of the same length, I'd reshape then aggregate:
d <- stack(data.frame(t(data.frame(foo))))
head(d)  
#   values ind
# 1      1  X1
# 2      1  X1
# 3      1  X1
# 4      1  X1
# 5      1  X1
# 6      1  X1

aggregate(values ~ ., data = d, 
          FUN = function(x) c(sum = sum(x), mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
#    ind values.sum values.mean values.sd
# 1   X1        100           1         0
# 2   X2        200           2         0
# 3   X3        300           3         0
# 4   X4        400           4         0
# 5   X5        500           5         0
# 6   X6        600           6         0
# 7   X7        700           7         0
# 8   X8        800           8         0
# 9   X9        900           9         0
# 10 X10       1000          10         0


One more alternative (faster than Reduce() and matrixStats) on my machine:
library(data.table)  
vapply(transpose(foo), sum, integer(1L))

which is beaten by a simple loop in Rcpp (although you will have to do consierably more work when applying different functions):
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("IntegerVector foo_cpp_loop(List foo, int n) {
  IntegerVector out(n, 0);
  IntegerVector current;
  for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++) {
    current = foo[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) out[j] += current[j];
  }
  return out;
}")

Benchmarking:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "apply_do.call" = apply(X = do.call(what = "data.frame", args = foo), MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sum", na.rm = TRUE),
  "apply_Reduce" = apply(X = Reduce(f = function(...) cbind(...), x = foo), MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sum", na.rm = TRUE),
  "Reduce" = Reduce(f = "+", x = foo),
  ms = matrixStats::rowSums2(do.call(what="cbind", args=foo)),
  transpose = vapply(transpose(foo), sum, integer(1L)),
  foo_cpp_loop(foo, 10L)
)
 #                   expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
 #          apply_do.call 4205.002 4358.6505 5061.20997 4545.1510 4839.8020 10788.100   100
 #           apply_Reduce  262.801  292.4510  323.45698  304.6005  333.6505  1188.500   100
 #                 Reduce   37.402   40.4510   45.34397   43.2005   47.4005   106.101   100
 #                     ms   20.101   22.4010   29.02693   29.1020   34.0005    60.101   100
 #              transpose   12.401   15.0510   20.70102   20.3010   24.2505    59.000   100
 # foo_cpp_loop(foo, 10L)    2.501    3.0005    6.85701    5.1005   10.5505    18.701   100

